# firebase_messaging version 3.0.0 failed to build with IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

when upgrade firebase_messaging to version 3.0.0 it is work correctly with android but in IOS build failed

```
 BUILD TARGET firebase_messaging OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug
    /Users/----/Libraries/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-3.0.0/ios/Classes/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:79:33: error: expected ')'
            instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult *_Nullable instanceIDResult,
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open up a terminal and navigate to your Flutter project directory.
Clean via `flutter clean`
Then cd into the iOS Folder and execute `pod install`
You may also want to update your pods via `pod update`

You may be able to run your project now.

Comment: I've updated my original answer. You may need to update your pods. Did this help?

Comment: still build failed

Comment: Are you sticking to 3.0.0 on purpose? Have you tried 4.0.0 ?

Comment: Can I see your output from pod install?